# R - plot smooth pie on worldmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatterpie

I am trying to plot pie charts on a worldmap. This is a simplified example of my code so far:

```
library(rworldmap)
library(ggplot2)
library(scatterpie)

WorldData <- map_data('world') 
toPlot <- data.frame(long = 0, lat = 0, r = 20, A = 5, B = 2, C = 10 )

dev.new();
ggplot( ) + 
  geom_polygon( data =  map_data('world') , aes(long, lat, group = group),
                fill = 'black', colour = 'grey', size=0.5 ) + 
  coord_fixed(1.3) + 
  
  geom_scatterpie(aes(x=long, y=lat, r=r ), 
                data = toPlot , cols=c("A", "B", "C"),
                color=NA, alpha=1, n = 1000 , linetype = 2 ) +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

The problem is that the piechart looks very crude. I tried changing the number of points used to draw the full circle (inherited from geom_arc_bar) and the linetype but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

How can I make it look smoother?

Comment: Don't you just need to make the plot bigger? The pie chart is quite small. If I make the whole plot about 640 x 480 pixels, the pie chart appears small and pixelated. If I make it full screen it looks fine

Comment: When I plot it full screen, it is still pixelated, as well as when I am saving it. I tried changing the resolution when using ```ggsave``` but it doesn't look better.